# KotlinJS and React, get change value from TextArea

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

Hello everyone I am trying to get value from textArea DOM but it doesn't seem to work like regular react

```
val chat = fc<ChatProps> { props ->
    val (mess, setMess) = useState("")

        div("flex flex-row bg-gray-400 m-4 py-2 px-1 mt-auto") {
            textarea(classes = "bg-transparent border-transparent w-full h-full border-opacity-0 " +
                    "scrollbar-hide w-full h-full") {
                attrs.value = mess
                attrs.onChange = {
                    console.log(it.target.nodeValue ?: "")
                }
            }
```

`it.target.value` is in React, it.currentTarget doesn't work either,casting the event T to be HTMLInputElement doesn't work either. It's always null. The classes are tailwind classes

Comment: Should `attrs.onChange` be a function instead of a statement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @tromgy, it is a lambda function and it receives the changeEvent as param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, will wait for someone to submit a better answer

```
 textarea() {
      attrs.value = mess
      attrs.onChangeFunction = {
         val ev = it as ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
         console.log(it.target.value)
         setMess(it.target.value)
    }
 }
```